# How to concatenate existing variable and string in Template Variables Dialog (PhpStorm)

Tags: phpstorm

I have a live template like this

```
<div>$name$: $id$</div>
```

Now I want to set the default value of $id$ to *name* + "_id".

But when I put the default value of $id$ as `name + "_id"`, in the "Edit Template Variables Dialog", the autocomplete does not concatenate value of *name* and (string) "_id" together. It only uses the value of *name* and ignored the "_id" part (for default value of $id$).

How can I make the default value of $id$ as `name + "_id"` in my live templates?

Comment: Please show your Live Template (body + variables).

Comment: Please see this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2LC0d.jpg. In the editor I type "test" and press `<tab>`. It automatically expands to `<div></div>` with the cursor after `<div>` where I type a word. So for example, the text should become `<div>foo = foo_id</div>` when my word is "foo", but instead it only becomes `<div>foo = foo</div>` (the "_id" part is ignored)

Comment: With your simple template .. do not use additional variable -- just `<div>$name$: $name$_id</div>` is enough

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that before but the simple template was an example to get the point across easily. The thing is $id$ is contained at least 4 times in the actual template, and while 8/10 times $id$ = name + "_id" but sometimes $id$ is different from $name$. So that's why I want to "default" it in the template so that in that case I can simply overwrite the entire value.

Comment: There is no dedicated `concat()` function .. and I could not find a way to concatenate 2 strings in any other way. If you would use full IntelliJ IDEA you [could use Groovy there](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155907#comment=27-1439617) and come up with something ... but it is not available in ordinary IDEs like PhpStorm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm only using PhpStorm as of now. Still appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a variable and concat the values into it.
Something like:

```
#set( $your_var = $NAME + '_id')

<div>$name$: $your_var$</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about phpstorm, but I was just looking for the solution to this problem in webstorm and there is a concat(expressions...) function. So, solution to the problem could be to put in the 'Expression' field:

```
concat(name,"_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
<div>$name$: $name$_id</div>
```